# Exclude/remove services from Dependency Indejection in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, dependency-injection

We currently have a project that consists of multiple applications as well as a base library.
Both, the applications as well as the base library contain stateless EJBs and each application might introduce an EJB that inherits from a base library EJBand thus implements the same interface.

A short example:

In the base library we have:

```
@Stateless
@Local( IUserService.class ) 
public UserServiceBean implements IUserService {
  public void login(String user, String password) {...}
}
```

In the application we need to override `login(...)` and thus we have:

```
@Stateless
@Local( { ISpecificUserService.class, IUserService.class } ) 
public SpecificUserServiceBean extends UserServiceBean implements ISpecificUserService {
  public void login(String user, String password) { ... } //override
}
```

If I now have another EJB in the application that needs to have a reference to `SpecificUserServiceBean` I'd do `@EJB ISpecificUserService userService;`.

However, if there is an EJB in the base library, it would contain `@EJB IUserService userService;` and here's the problem:

We need to get the specific service in the application be injected in the base library EJB. However, there are two EJBs registered for the same local interface, which means that the container might return the base EJB or the specific EJB.

You could say "Don't add the base library jar as a module in application.xml" but that's not possible right now, since it contains other EJBs that need to be deployed. We could move the EJBs to be overridden to a different jar but since almost every EJB might be overridden, depending on the application, we'd end up with a jar per EJB.

Thus, I'd like to exclude or remove the base EJB from the dependency injection container if there exists a specific override. Since I know that at deploy time, I could also use a configuration file to tell the container not to load a specific EJB class.

I might add a service that modifies the container afterwards but that would be my last resort.

Do you have any ideas on what we could do?

Thanks in advance.

Btw, we're working on JBoss 4.2.3 with EJB 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're wiring your app partially in the base lib which is bad since you can't override this wiring.

So the solution is to remove `@Stateless @Local( IUserService.class )` from `UserServiceBean` in your base lib; the base lib just provides default implementations for the beans but it must not wire them.

In your apps, you need this code:

```
@Stateless
@Local( IUserService.class ) 
public AppUserServiceBean extends UserServiceBean {}
```

to create the wiring. Move all those beans into a special package which you can copy into each app so you get the default wiring for everything.

Comment: That would be a solution, too. However, that would require us to duplicate all our EJBs in each application, even if they are just used for the wiring.

Comment: I just found JBoss 5's jboss-scanning.xml which might be solution if we could switch over to JBoss 5. With that file we might be able to exclude the base services from scanning and they thus wouldn't be deployed. I'd still have to test that, though.

Comment: Spring solves the same problem with layering: You can load contexts in a tree and the parent layers hide the lower layers. It breaks if the lower layers already created beans (existing beans don't get the new, overwritten beans injected). But if you load all layers at startup (which you usually do), this works pretty well.

Comment: @Aaron This sounds like a nice solution, thanks. Unfortunately I doubt I can get my boss to allow a fundamental restructuring from EJB 3 to Spring. If there isn't a way to do that using EJB 3+ I might be able to convince him, though.

Comment: @Thomas: I mentioned Spring as an example; I'm not suggesting that you switch to it - unless you can't solve the problem. In that case, the maintenance effort should be considered vs. converting *a part* of your application to Spring. Spring is a non-invasive technology. You don't have to give up EJB and you don't have to use it everywhere.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I suspected so. I'll have a deeper look into Spring and I'll see where that leads me. Thanks.

Comment: If all else fails: It's just Java code. So there should be a way to get the source for the set of classes which handle these annotations and change them. I understand that a lot of people shy away from changing "standard" code and why - but if it solves the problem, it solves the problem. Modern VCS can get you a long way to maintain a fork of, say, the Java runtime.

Comment: @Aaron I have the corresponding source for the container we use, so I might try and change that as well. However, I'd like to have a more portable aproach (not specific for a certain JBoss version), so I'll look into Spring first. Thanks again.